# Can't pass more than one anonymous parameters in URL via ajax

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm trying to send some Ids via route values with my data in my ajax call and I'm having issues passing more than one.

This is what I'm having to do now... Then split it out into an array on the server.

```
@Url.Action("Save", "MyController", New With {.Ids = ViewData("Id1") & "," &   ViewData("Id2") & "," & ViewData("Id3") & "," & ViewData("Id4")})");
```

This is what I would like to do:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Save", "MyController", New With {.Id1 = ViewData("Id1"), .Id2 = ViewData("Id2"), .Id3 = ViewData("Id3")})";

$.ajax({            
    type: "POST",            
    dataType: "json",            
    url: urlString,
    data: json,                     
    success: function(data) {                                  

}

});
```

controller method signature:

```
<HttpPost()> _
    Function Save(ByVal json As String, ByVal Id1 As String, ByVal Id2 As String, ByVal Id3 As String) As JsonResult
```

I have also tried using a class instead like this(MyClass has corresponding property names to the parameters I am passing in):

```
<HttpPost()> _
    Function Save(ByVal json As String, theClass as MyClass) As JsonResult
```

JSON data looks like:

```
"json={'control1' : 'test1', 'control2' : 'test2'}"
```

Parameter values: Id1 is an integer, Id2 a guid and Id3 an integer.

Unfortunately when I try this I will only get my first param and the rest are nothing.

Any advice would much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could send a JSON request:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "FormGeneration")';

var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(New With { .Id1 = ViewData("Id1"), .Id2 = ViewData("Id2"), .Id3 = ViewData("Id3") }));
// assign some other properties
jsonData.foo = 'bar';

$.ajax({            
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    success: function(data) {                                  

    }
});
```

This will successfully invoke and pass parameters to the following action:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Create(ByVal id1 As Integer, ByVal id2 As Integer, ByVal id3 As Integer, ByVal foo As SomeViewModel) As ActionResult
    ...
End Function
```

You also can send those integers as an array:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "FormGeneration")';

var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(New With { .ids = { ViewData("Id1"), ViewData("Id2"), ViewData("Id3") } }));
// assign some other properties
jsonData.foo = 'bar';

$.ajax({            
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    success: function(data) {                                  

    }
});
```

which will be bound to the following action:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Create(ByVal ids As Integer(), ByVal foo As SomeViewModel) As ActionResult
    ...
End Function
```

But if you already have a view model (which you should by the way), the Ids could directly be a property of your view model so that your controller action now looks like this:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Create(ByVal foo As SomeViewModel) As ActionResult
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  These are great alternatives but I'm wondering why my preferred solution will not work?

Comment: @Hidan, I have strictly no idea. You haven't shown the signature of controller action you are attempting to invoke. How do you expect me knowing why your code doesn't work without actually showing your code?

Comment: My apologize I didn't realize I hadn't included it... I've update the original post!

Comment: @Hidan, alright now that you have shown your server side code, you will have to show what does the `urlString` and `json` variables that you are using in your `$.ajax` have as values. All I can see is some `url` variable which you doesn't seem to be using anywhere.

Comment: Ok, I've added the json data and parameter types.  The Json data I am getting fine as well as the first parameter that is passed in.  If I rearrange the orders of the parameter so that the guid is first or the other integers I will get them as well just not the other two that follow...

Comment: @Hidan, I don't understand exactly what the problem is. You don't seem to be setting the `contentType: 'application/json'` parameter in your AJAX request and yet you are attempting to send JSON?

Comment: It's a string in json format that is build dynamically on save. I serialize that into another object on the server.